# C# WebBrowser Javascript not running

Tags: c#

I am loading a URL using C# WebBrowser Controller.  In that URL there is  form and there is a radio button invoking a Javascript function.

When you click a radio button it call a JavaScript function

```
 <input
 id="rdoCash" language="javascript"
 onclick="__doPostBack('rdoCash','')" name="PaymentType"
 value="rdoCash" type="radio">
```

But this function is not called withing the WebBrowserControl. But if I open the same URL using IE then this JavaScript is working.

Why Web Browser Control disabling this Javascript command.

Please help

Comment: How do you load the HTML in the WebBrowser control?

Comment: using webBrowser.Navigate()  method

Comment: Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: Is this something to do with IE. I am using 9. I enabled all options I can but not effected to this.

Comment: have you tried calling a simple alert javascript ... The IE version depends on the .NEt framework version I think.